# Pegar o html de uma variavel criada

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema para concatenar variáveis que já criei (conheco `.concat()`) e tudo mais.

Problema:

```
    var input1 = $('input').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        value: 1
    });

    var input1_2 = $('input').attr({
        type : 'text',
        size : '14',
        name : 'nomeTorre',
        id   : 'nomeTorre',
        class: 'form-control'
    });
```

sei que usa < > mas não estava mostrando aqui entao tirei.

```
var dadosexemplo = input1 + input_2;
```

ou `.concat` não funcionou

resultado : [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]

Como eu poderia criar as variáveis dessa forma , sem fazer isso:

```
var input1 = "input type='text' value='1'"
```

estou querendo mudar tudo que esta dessa forma para essa citada ali em cima. Mas sempre me retorna um object ,e JSON.string... não resolve.

Quero criar variáveis da primeira forma, concatenar elas para criar um 'bloco' literalmente e depois jogar na página .php.

Resumindo, eu tenho da forma mais feia. O html todo dentro de um " " e quero mudar para deixar melhor a visualização e manutenção no futuro.

Answer (score 3):

> **Nota:** não havia percebido que a pergunta usava jQuery, a resposta abaixo utiliza JS puro.

Não entendo o motivo de querer converter tudo para string antes de dar a saída. Se você já tem os elementos criados como nós do DOM, o melhor é continuar usando esse método. Você pode simplesmente criar um container e colocar seu conteúdo lá dentro. E depois pendurar esse container no lugar adequado do seu HTML, usando o mesmo método. Algo assim:

```
// Criação dos inputs como você já faz
// ...

// Criação do container
var container = document.createElement('div');

// Coloca os inputs no container
container.appendChild(input1);
container.appendChild(input2);
// Ou container.appendChild(input1[0]) se input1 for jQuery

// Coloca o container no HTML
// (neste exemplo, direto no <body>
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Ou, se não quiser o container na estrutura final, você pode mover o que tem nele para outro lugar, substituindo a última linha acima por:

```
// Move todo o conteúdo para outro nó
while(container.fistChild) {
    document.body.appendChild(container.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado mano , ajudou bastante para eu ter a ideia.

Answer (score 2):

tente isso, funciona perfeitamente para mim:

```
var dadosexemplo = input1.prop('outerHTML') + input1_2.prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: Realmente funciona , mas ja tinha usado da outra forma, mas obrigado.

Comment: @RodrigoLuan, é nóis tamo junto!

Answer (score 1):

Da pra fazer desta forma também, somente com **javascript**, criando os objetos e posteriormente criando os elementos html, p/ deixar no formato de string utilizei o atributo [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), segue o snippet de exemplo:

```js
var input1_element = {
  tag: 'input',
  attr: {
    id: "hue",
    type: 'hidden',
    value: 1
  }
};

var input2_element = {
  tag: 'input',
  attr: {
    type: 'text',
    size: '14',
    name: 'nomeTorre',
    id: 'nomeTorre',
    class: 'form-control'
  }
};

var input1 = document.createElement(input1_element.tag);
for (var attr in input1_element.attr) {
  input1.setAttribute(attr, input1_element.attr[attr]);
}

var input2 = document.createElement(input2_element.tag);
for (var attr in input2_element.attr) {
  input2.setAttribute(attr, input2_element.attr[attr]);
}

var dadosexemplo = input1.outerHTML + input2.outerHTML
console.log(dadosexemplo);
```

Comment: Como seu metodo foi o primeiro a me ajudar, usei da sua forma. Obrigado Mathias

Comment: @RodrigoLuan Mas não tenha esse fato como parâmetro, avalie as outras respostas também, se tiver uma que você julgar melhor para sua aplicação, faça uso dela, fico feliz que tenha ajudado :)

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso, aqui funcionou:

```js
var input1 = $('input').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: 1
        });

        var input1_2 = $('input').attr({
            type : 'text',
            size : '14',
            name : 'nomeTorre',
            id   : 'nomeTorre',
            class: 'form-control'
        });
        var dadosexemplo = JSON.stringify(input1) + JSON.stringify(input1_2); 
        console.log(dadosexemplo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Value, mas queria a tag html, nao cada parte da string. Mas obrigado.

Comment: Puts, perdão, entendi errado então. Vou tentar resolver isso, ja volto.

Comment: Relaxa , de boa, obrigado por tentar ajudar, só por isso já agradeço.